# How to change border color in tkinter widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, border, tk-toolkit

I want to know how should I chnage border color of tkinter Label or Button , I put the releif in `solid` and the border color would be black . i have tried `highlightthickness`,`highlightcolor`,`highlightbackground` but it doesnt work

here is a sample of my code :

```
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x450")
root.title("How should i change border color")
tk.Label(root,text = "How should i change border color",width = 50 , height = 4 ,bg = "White",relief = "solid").place(x=10,y=10)
tk.Button(root,text = "Button",width = 5 , height = 1 ,bg = "White",relief = "solid").place(x=100,y=100)


root.mainloop()
```

and here is what i want to change(the border color that is Black now , I want to change it to red) :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vqen.png)

I have tried What you said [@moshe-perez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7831455/moshe-perez) but it doesnt work:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ5Vq.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `highlightbackground` you need to provide a color code, for example `"#37d3ff"`.
So use `highlightbackground="COLORCODE"` and remove `relief="solid"`

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x450")
root.title("How should i change border color")
tk.Label(root, text="How should i change border color", width=50, height=4, bg="White", highlightthickness=4, highlightbackground="#37d3ff").place(x=10, y=10)
tk.Button(root, text="Button", width=5, height=1, bg="White", highlightbackground="#37d3ff").place(x=100, y=100)


root.mainloop()
```

result:

[image]

Update: While it workes on my ubuntu machine, I just checked it on windows and it doesn't work there.

Comment: sorry but it doesnt work , the borders are still black but in diffrent style

Comment: @A._.P._.G hmm I tested it and it works on my computer. maybe it only works on Linux?

Comment: I dont know , Maybe , is it possible for you to send me a photo ? i want to see how it look like

Comment: @A._.P._.G added a screenshot

Comment: thank you , but in my computer its still black

Comment: Excuse me , which python version do you use ?

Comment: @A._.P._.G I'm using python 3.7.3

Comment: my python version is 3.7 too , and you use manjaro true?

Comment: @A._.P._.G No, I use Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way in tkinter to change the border color. One of the workarounds I used was making a slightly bigger label in root, and putting my label into that.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x450")
root.title("How should i change border color")
border = tk.Label(root, width=52, height=5, bg='red')
border.place(x=10, y=10)
tk.Label(border, text="How should i change border color", width=50, height=4, bg="White", highlightthickness=4, highlightbackground="#37d3ff").place(x=1, y=1)
tk.Button(root, text="Button", width=5, height=1, bg="White", highlightbackground="#37d3ff").place(x=100, y=100)


root.mainloop()
```

Not pretty, but it works.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Daniel , Its good way for labels but for Buttons it wouldnt be pretty as you said

Comment: _"AFAIK, there is no way in tkinter to change the background color"_ - did you mean _border_ color"? The background color is easy to change.

Comment: Yes, I did. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

this might be helpful, as I used `Frame`

I could be able to change the background color.

```
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x450")
root.title("How should i change border color")
border = tk.Frame(root, background="green")
label = tk.Label(border, text="How should i change border color", bd=5)
label.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=5, pady=5)
border.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
button1 = tk.Button(root, background="green")
name = tk.Button(button1, text="click", bd=0)
name.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)
button1.pack(padx=20, pady=20)


root.mainloop()
```

Lengthy but worked.

Comment: its ok for label but when you set a button under another one  if user click on the button nothing would happen to the border(button1) and when user push the border(button1)...